# Response for FileUploader's uploadComplete-Event is undefined

Tags: javascript, file-upload, sapui5

I'm developing a SAPUI5 app and use the FileUploader control in my app to upload documents to a server. The uploading works and I also receive a response from the server (I can see this in the DevTools of Chrome).
The problem is that the event-object inside the 'uploadComplete' event-handler always returns undefined for the response parameter.

Do you know why this is the case and how I can fix it?

Here is the initialization of the FileUploader:

```
var oFileUploader = new sap.ui.unified.FileUploader({
    uploadUrl: "/fileupload",
    name: "documentUploader",
    uploadOnChange: false,
    multiple: false,
    width: "400px",
    uploadComplete: this.onDocumentUploadComplete
});
```

And here is the 'uploadComplete' event-handler:

```
onDocumentUploadComplete: function(oEvent) {
    var response = oEvent.getParameter("response");
    console.log(response);      // response = undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't figured out how to receive the server's response but I have found a workaround.
After uploading the file I just send a request to the server and tell it to check whether the file exists.
If it exists the server returns "true" and if it doesn't the server returns "false". Here's my code:

```
// eventhandler for the "uploadComplete"-event of the FileUploader-control
onDocumentUploadComplete: function(oEvent) {
    var uploaderControl = oEvent.getSource();
    var documentname = uploaderControl.getValue();

    var fileURI = "/file/" + documentname + "?exists";
    $.get(fileURI, function(data) {
        if (data === "true") {
            console.log("Successfully uploaded: " + documentname);
            this.handleDocumentUploadSuccess(documentname);
        } else {
            console.log("Error when uploading document: " + documentname);
            this.handleDocumentUploadError(documentname);
        }
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.unified.FileUploader/events) the parameter `response` is subject to some conditions.

> Response message which comes from the server. On the server side this
>   response has to be put within the "body" tags of the response document
>   of the iFrame. It can consist of a return code and an optional
>   message. This does not work in cross-domain scenarios.

That means the response fom the server must be XML or HTML.

Comment: This is an example of a response i get:  <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Error report</title></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Uploaded file is not an image from the allowed range! (allowed file types: gif, png, jpg, bmp)</h1></body></html>  Shouldn't this work?

Comment: The documentation also says "This does not work in cross-domain scenarios." and I think this applies here. The server I'm uploading to is a Java server deployed on the Hana Cloud Platform, while my SAPUI5 application is a separate application which is deployed to a SAP Fiori Launchpad. But if I can't receive a response from the server then how can my app tell whether the upload was successful or not? (By the way: I also tried getting the filename with oEvent.getParameter("fileName") but that's also undefined. The documentation doesn't list any conditions for the fileName parameter though)

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I am doing cross domain and get undefined for both the event as well as the fileName parameter as per the above comment

Comment: Setting sendXHR to true allows the responseRaw parameter to be used.

Comment: For those that dont know, `sendXHR` is a property of `unified.FileUploader`. From `UploadSet`, u can access its `FileUploader` with `getDefaultFileUploader()`